# What is a build number in Xcode

Tags: xcode

What does "Build Number" mean in Xcode. I am developing a iOS app. Is it the amount of times that I have debugged my applications?

I've tried researching it but for some reason I just can't seem to find out what it means in Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just helps you determine which version is newer than another, when you publish a new version in AppStore this must be modified and be higher.

For example you can use the following correlation in name versions.

- Name Version: 3.0
- Build Number: 3000
- Name Version: 2.4.12
- Build Number: 2412